# Android bindService not working

Tags: android, service, bind, aidl

I'm having an issue with `bindService()`. I'm trying to do the binding in a constructor, providing an Intent that contains two parcleable extras. The constructor is being called in `onResume()` and the service, in its `onBind()` method, parses the two extras and may return `null` as a result of the parsing.

When I first run the app (through the Run in Eclipse) the binding is (expectedly) rejected by the service: the service's `onBind()` method is called and returns `null`. However, the `bindService()` method, on the application side, returns `true` (it shouldn't, as the binding did not go through!).

This gets more problematic when I try the following: I press the HOME button and start the app again (so its `onResume()` runs again and the app tries to bind to the service again). This time the service's `onBind()` seems not to be even run! But the app's `bindService()` still returns `true`!

Below is some sample code that should help you understand my issue.

The application side:

```
// activity's onResume()
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    var = new Constructor(this);
}

// the constructor
public Constructor(Context context) {
    final Intent bindIntent = new Intent("test");

    bindIntent.putExtra("extra1",extra_A);
    bindIntent.putExtra("extra2",extra_B);

    isBound = context.bindService(bindIntent, connection, Context.BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY);

    log("tried to bind... isBound="+isBound);
}
```

The service side:

```
private MyAIDLService service = null;   

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    service = new MyAIDLService(getContentResolver());
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
    log("onBind() called");     

    if (intent.getAction().equals("test") {
        ExtraObj extra_A = intent.getParcelableExtra("extra1");
        ExtraObj extra_B = intent.getParcelableExtra("extra2");

        if (parse(extra_A,extra_B))
            return service;
        else {
            log("rejected binding");
            return null;
        }

     }
}
```

The `ServiceConnection` that I'm using holds the following `onServiceConnected()` method:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(final ComponentName name, final IBinder service) {
    log("onServiceConnected(): successfully connected to the service!");

    this.service = MyAIDLService.asInterface(service);
}
```

So, I never get to see the "successfully connected to the service!" log. The first time I run the app (through Eclipse) I'm getting the "rejected binding" log as well as "isBound=true", but from there on I only get the "isBound=true", the "rejected binding" doesn't come up ever again.

I suspect that this might have to do with a possibility of Android recognizing that there was a successful bind even when I forced the rejection. Ideally, I would be able to force an 'unbind' too, but that's not possible: I suspect this because, when I kill the app, I'm getting a log that's located in the `onUnbind()` method of the service (even though there should be no binding in the first place!).

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue, but realized that my service was not actually being started.  Perhaps try adding "Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE" to the flags, which will cause the service to be created and started.  I don't believe that Context.BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY will start it, so the onServiceConnected may not be called (it wasn't for me even though the bindService() call was returning true):

```
    isBound = context.bindService(bindIntent, connection,
          Context.BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY | Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```